# Tomcat 6 is not working in eclipse AND windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat6

I have installed Tomcat 6 in Windows 7 and I want to execute a sample servlet program, but it's not working.

Problem: When I run the code, the external Tomcat is shutdown, `localhost:8090/Helloworld -> 404 error raised`.

I need a proper setting to set up and run a "SERVLET PRGM" from Eclipse.

Softwares used:

- Eclipse Europa
- Tomcat 6
- Jre 7, Jdk 7
- Windows 7

Comment: What's the path of your tomcat-installation?

Comment: What's a "SERVLET PRGM"? ;)

Comment: Path `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation`

Comment: "SERVLET PRGM" means sample project with servlet program.("HelloWorld") @Stefan

Comment: A servlet does not just cause a server to shutdown. If that happens you have way deeper problems than faulty code. Check the server logs.

Comment: Where did you find the sample program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/eclipse.html

you can see this website,it can help you.